# Valgrind: Invalid read / write of size 1

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to build a very basic web server using `C`. I have solved all of the problems reported by `valgrind` except this one. This is the relevant piece of code that causes it. I have added `x>>` to the lines that `valgrind` suggests:

```
/* Set the response header. */
char *response_header = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "\r\n";

/* Try to load the 404 message. Return 0 if failed. */
int response_body_size = 0;
char *response_body = read_file(FILE_404, &response_body_size);
if (response_body == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
terminate_string(response_body, response_body_size);

/* Allocate space to merge the header and body and merge them. Return 0 if failed. */
1>> char *response = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(response_header) + strlen(response_body)));
if (response == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
strcpy(response, response_header);
2,3>> strcat(response, response_body);

/* Return the response. */
4>> write(connection_fd, response, strlen(response));
```

`terminate_string():`

```
/* Adds the terminating character to the specified string. */
void terminate_string(char *str, int length) {
5>> str[length] = '\0';
}
```

`read_file():`

```
/* Reads the specified file and returns its contents. Will return NULL if could not read. */
/* Assumes the filename starts with a / character! */
void* read_file(char *filename, int *file_size) {
    /* Open the file in binary read mode. Return NULL if failed. */
    FILE *file = fopen(filename + 1, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Get the size of the file. Return NULL if failed.*/
    struct stat fs;
    if (fstat(fileno(file), &fs) == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    *file_size = fs.st_size;

    /* Read the contents to a string. */
    void* result = NULL;
6>> result = (void *) malloc (fs.st_size);
    /* Return NULL if malloc failed. */
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    fread(result, 1, *file_size, file);

    /* Close the file. */
    fclose(file);

    return result;
}
```

Valgrind report:

```
1: Invalid read of size 1 [PID: 3896]
2: Invalid read of size 1 [PID:3896]
3: Invalid write of size 1 [PID:3896]
4: Invalid read of size 1 [PID:3896]
5: Invalid write of size 1 [PID:3896]
6: Address 0x541bbb4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd [PID: 3896]
```

For some reason, the `read_file()` function returns 2 extra characters. This appears to be solved by `terminate_string()` but obviously valgrind knows something I don't. I have been looking at this code for the past 3 hours while reading every possible solution I found online and I didn't manage to figure it out. I am very new to dynamic memory allocation in C so it might be very obvious to someone with experience.

**What is the problem here and how could I fix it?**

Also, **why is read_file() returning 2 bytes more than the file contains?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, well done for using `valgrind`.

At point 6, you do:

```
result = (void *) malloc (fs.st_size);
```

I suggest you do:

```
size_t sz = fs.st_size;
result = malloc (sz+1); /* no need to cast return of malloc() */
((char *)result)[sz] = 0; /* zero terminate it */
```

As the problem you have is that you have `malloc`'d *exactly* sufficient room for the file and the body, but not the terminating `NUL`.

Your `terminate_string` idea is broken as that writes beyond the end of `response_body`. If the response body is zero terminated you don't need that, so can drop it.

For a similar reason, you want:

```
char *response = malloc(sizeof(char) *
                 (strlen(response_header) + strlen(response_body) + 1));
```

`+1` being for the `NUL`.

However, there is a bigger problem: HTTP documents themselves can contain `\0`, i.e. zero bytes, in which case you cannot `strlen()` them. A better fix would therefore be to `write` the response header, then `write` the response body, and simply keep the size of the body around as an integer. I've explained what the problem is above as it's important you know.

Comment: "*HTTP documents themselves can contain \0*" could they?

Comment: `NULL` is not "null". The "null"-terminator, a character of value `'\0'` is called `NUL`.

Comment: @alk - re NUL, thanks, fixed, insufficient caffeine. And re HTTP documents containing `\0` yes absolutely they can. If it starts of with a `Content-Type` saying it's a `png` for instance, then it can contain a 0. Quite legal even for a `404` document. More likely however is a gzip compressed error document, which I'm sure is not hard to find.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Also, that was a good observation. Do you happen to also know why the read_file() function is returning 2 extra bytes?

Comment: @abligh: Yes sure, correct. I was with smtp, where binaries are encode base64, which is not necessarily the case for http. Thanks.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki no, but I suggest you dump `file_size`, the output of the `stat` and the return value from `fread` and see where it goes wrong.