# How to address the Valgrind invalid read / write of size 1 & Address # is 0 bytes after a block of size x alloc'd in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I see this Valgrind issue of invalid read / write of size 1 & Address # is 0 bytes after a block of size x alloc'd is quite commonplace and I am unable to quite pinpoint in my context.

For some background, I am making a dynamic string encoding function:

I declare a calloc'd buffer as so:
`char * buffer = calloc( 4, sizeof(char) );`

I declare another variable that will hold the building encoding string as:
`char * encoded_str = calloc(5, sizeof(char));`

The string sequence of the buffer and the returned encoded string should be 3 and 4 chars respectively. I have alloc'd a one character padding each per the plethora of posts concerning this topic, such as:

[Valgrind: Invalid read / write of size 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126188/valgrind-invalid-read-write-of-size-1)

I imagined that zero-terminating all my strings would be the move but it is not resolving the issue.

Proceeding onward:

I read 3 bytes of a file into the buffer as so:
`fread( buffer, sizeof(char), 3, in_file );`

and I similarly null-terminate it:
`buffer[3] = '\0';`

I have the desire to call my encoder function on buffer with the expectation that it will be stored in encoded_str as such:
`encoded_str = encoder( buffer );`

However, I have a memory leak as:

```
==77225== HEAP SUMMARY:
==77225==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==77225==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 582 bytes allocated

==74372== 5 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==74372==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==74372==    by 0x400C78: sendToEncoder (enc.c:139)
```

where line 139 corresponds to the `char * encoded_str = calloc(5, sizeof(char));`

This encoded_str is the return product of the function and I null terminate after this call for consistency sake.

The output is correct where the input is literally just "fo".

There is a lot more complexity but the fact that the program is erroring in this most basic of cases tells me there is some basic aspect of memory allocation / management that I am missing that is propagating as the clauses get more complex and encoded_str builds.

Comment: A small novel telling us how you think your code works is nowhere *near* as productive to finding your problem as providing a proper [mcve]. barring that, If you're using address sanitizer along with your *debugger*, it can help immensely with tracking down breaches. Best of luck.

Comment: The `invalid read / write of size 1 & Address # is 0 bytes after a block of size x alloc'd` message means you're reading or writing beyond the end of the character array you're accessing.  You aren't allocating enough space (did you allocate an extra byte for the null byte that terminates a string?) or you're simply running your loops out of bounds.

Comment: I know this was a bit verbose but my problem stems at dynamic memory declaration & allocation of the encoded_str variable `char * encoded_str = calloc(5, sizeof(char));` prior to any initialization so I am left a little dumbfounded as to what the root of the issue is.